# Why can't some of the properties on the HTMLScriptElement be assigned to in TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, typescript, dom

I'm using TypeScript and React.
I have a simple function which should copy script attributes from one to another:

```
type MutableScriptProperties = Pick<
  HTMLScriptElement,
  'async' | 'crossOrigin' | 'defer' | 'integrity' | 'noModule' | 'referrerPolicy' | 'type' | 'nonce'
>;

type Values<T extends object> = T[keyof T];

type MutableScriptKey = keyof MutableScriptProperties;

type MutableScriptValue = Values<MutableScriptProperties>;

const scriptPropertiesToClone: MutableScriptKey[] = [
  'async',
  'crossOrigin',
  'defer',
  'integrity',
  'noModule',
  'nonce',
  'referrerPolicy',
  'type',
];

function cloneScriptProperties(source: HTMLScriptElement, target: HTMLScriptElement): HTMLScriptElement {
  scriptPropertiesToClone.forEach((propKey) => {
    const sourceValue = source[propKey] as MutableScriptValue;

    if (sourceValue !== undefined) {
       target[propKey] = sourceValue; // this line throws an error
    }
  });
  return target;
}
```

On the line marked with a comment, I'm getting following error:

```
Type 'string | boolean | null' is not assignable to type 'never'.
  Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'never'.ts(2322)
```

Is there any reason why any of these the HTMLScriptTag props would return or be marked as `never`?
What is the correct solution that doesn't involve casting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason `target[propKey]` is inferred to `never`. I don't have actual solution but rather workaround (that involves casting)

```
   (target[propKey] as unknown as MutableScriptValue) = sourceValue
```

Comment: The "some reason" here is [microsoft/TypeScript#30769](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/30769), a [change](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Breaking-Changes#fixes-to-unsound-writes-to-indexed-access-types) in TS3.5 to improve soundness for indexed access.  There is a suggestion at [microsoft/TypeScript#32693](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/32693) with a [comment](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/32693#issuecomment-598860475) on it indicating that this may be addressed someday, but for now you need a type assertion ("casting") or the like.